# Detect a view % for video in <video> element?

Tags: javascript, video, playback

Is there a way to detect how much of a video in a `video` element has been viewed? For instance, if I wanted to trigger an event only after a person has viewed 80% of a video, is that possible? Or am I confined to only detecting if the `ended` event has fired?

Comment: Yes! The `timeupdate` event is emitted about every second. `const el = document.querySelector('video'); el.addEventListener('timeupdate', evt => { const pct = el.currentTime / el.duration * 100; console.log(\`Video is  ${pct}% watched\`); });`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!